# Can I play Fortnite on a phone with a Mediatek Helio G35 chipset, like the Nokia G20?

Tags: android, fortnite-battle-royale

I am considering buying the Nokia G20, which has the Mediatek Helio G35 chipset. Will I be able to play Fortnite on that device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you will not be able to play Fortnite on the Nokia G20. Unfortunately, the GPU listed for that device falls considerably under the requirements.

---

According to the Epic Games store, the Android version of Fortnite has the following system requirements:

> **Q:** What are the minimum device specifications to play Fortnite?
>
> **A:** Fortnite is a high-fidelity game that is compatible with devices running 64-bit Android on an ARM64 processor, Android OS 8.0 or higher, minimum 4GB of RAM, and GPU: Adreno 530 or higher, Mali-G71 MP20, Mali-G72 MP12 or higher. 
> **[- Epic Games Fortnite FAQ, Android section](https://www.epicgames.com/fortnite/en-US/faq)**

The Mediatek Helio G35 chipset uses the Imagination PowerVR GE8320 GPU. Having run a lot of comparisons, it falls quite a bit under the specifications of the Qualcomm Adreno 530. I was finally able to find one site that ran a direct comparison, showing over 10 times the difference in performance<sup>[1](https://gadgetversus.com/graphics-card/imagination-powervr-ge8320-vs-qualcomm-adreno-530/)</sup>. TechCenturion.com outright list the GPU as being unsupported<sup>[2](https://compare.techcenturion.com/adreno-610-vs-powervr-ge8320/#can-it-run-games)</sup>.